# setting java tmp directory for a specific application deployed on websphere

Tags: java, crystal-reports, websphere

I'm faced with a problem related to changing the java.io.tmp for just one application (called **app1**) by doing this :  `System.setProperty("java.io.tmpdir",'specific path');` .
Unfortunately, during performing tests, it was revealed tha the java.io.tmp has been changed for all application deployed on the websphere application server 8.0.
Is there any solution to fix that? I would really appreciate any help.

NB : the **app1** is using JRC ( java runtime component) of crystal report and it generate huge tmp files under /tmp. that's why i want to change the java io tmp.

Answer (score 2):

System properties are global to the JVM, so you cannot define a system property to apply to a single application on an application server - anything defined in a system property will apply to all apps and even the server runtime itself.  There's no way to limit a system property definition to just an application scope.

The best solution is probably going to be seeing if the tool you're using is configurable to use some other definition for its temp location; if not, you will probably have to take it up with the provider or see if there's a way to add your own extension.